# How to change image in ActionBar (Material Design) from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-appbarlayout

Looking at the material design `actionbar` with image, see [Flexible space with image](http://www.materialdoc.com/scrolling-techniques/) an `ImageView` is placed into the `AppBarLayout`.
If one creates an `Activity` with a `Fragment` in Android Studio, it makes an `activity.xml`, `content_activity.xml` and `fragment.xml`:

activity.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.app.MyActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="172dp"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:titleEnabled="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/banner_image"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_activity" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_activity.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.app.MyActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

fragment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...>
...
</RelaviteLayout>
```

My question is, how could one change the `ImageView` image in the `AppbarLayout` (see link above) from the `Fragment` dynamically in code?
Changing the Actionbar title is as simple as `getActivity().setTitle("New_Title");` but how to reference and change an image in an `ImageView` also located in the `AppBarLayout` is just beyond me.

I've tried:

in MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView banner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        banner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bannerImageView);
    }

    void setBanner(int imgId) {

        if (banner != null) {
            banner.setImageResource(imgId);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "banner is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

in Fragment.java:

```
int imgId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(arrayItem.getBanner(),
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
    ((MyActivity) getActivity()).setBanner(imgId);
```

but the reference is null.

Comment: I can't find where is the bannerImageView in your XML.

Comment: @HoangNguyen, sorry, I haden't added it because I was referring to the code in the link. I've added it now so that it's clearer for you and everyone else. Thanks.

Comment: Which reference is null? And could you change the name of your Activity to something like MyActivity, at least as long as your problem persists? Somehow I'm wondering what the cast to Activity in your last line of code really does.

Comment: Renamed & no change. The `banner` `ImageView` in the last method of  `MyActivity` seems to be null because it always displays the `Toast` popup instead of setting the image.

Answer (score 1):

Add `imageView` to the `AppBarLayout`.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

You can either use callbacks or declare a method in your activity and use it by calling `getActivity()` (Warning: This is not the right method because fragments are supposed to be used with multiple activities).

I suppose you're using only single activity i.e, MainActivity

Declare this function : `setImage()` in the MainActivity.class

```
public void setImage(Drawable drawable){
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

Also, bind reference to the imageView in onCreate()

```
imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Now, you can call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setImage(drawable)` in the fragment.

---

**Problem with the reference**
The above call to `setImage()` should not be called in the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment.

Because the fragment view is instantiated when `setContentView()` is called in the `onCreate()` method of the activity. The stub code generated by android studio statically adds the fragment to the layout of the activity.

This is the sequence of calls that take place -

- `Activity : onCreateView()`
- `Activity : setContentView()`
- `Fragment : onCreate()`
- `Fragment : onCreateView()`
- `Instructions after setContentView()`
- `Fragment : onActivityCreated()`

In your code, you've bound the reference to banner after `setContentView()` and you may be calling the `setBanner()` before this bind occurs.

So to successfully bind the reference and set the image,by overriding `onActivityCreated()` in your fragment class and calling `setBanner()` there.

Comment: Sorry, but in trying to keep my question short, I made it too vague. I've added all the rest and if you look, you'll see that I did just what you're saying. If I don't surround the part where it sets the image in the imageView with an `if` statement, then it throws a nullobjectreference excepetion. As it is, it toasts, "imageView is null".

Comment: If imageView is null, then that means you're passing the data in wrong way. What is the value of imgId?

Comment: I've added it at the bottom in the question. It takes `String` values from a database. I know imgId to work fine, because if I apply it to another `ImageView`, it displays the correct image.

Comment: @inferKNOX Instead of  `getActivity().getResources()...` try `getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(arrayItem.getBanner(),
                "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());` .  Why are storing them into a database? If I may ask? Because there is better way to store them.

Comment: Well I have an array of a lot of items displayed in a RecyclerView, each with a lot of details, then when an item is clicked, this activity is opened and the data corresponding to the clicked item is fetched from the database, placed in an object and used to populate the activity. It's the most efficient way I've found to store all the data so far. If there is a better way, I don't know it yet. I'm new in dev. For example, I don't know the difference between getActivity() and getContext().  I used getContext() now and the result is still the same.

Comment: Just read about getActivity and getContext and think I understand it now. ^_^

Comment: Oh yeah, right, since you have the same activity (i.e, DetailActivity) getActivity and getContext refer the same activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125361/discussion-between-gurupad-mamadapur-and-inferknox).

Answer (score 0):

After doing much testing, even trying to set the image in `OnAttach` in the `Fragment` and also trying to declare the image variable in the `Activity` instead, I came to realise that it is something to do with lifecycles.

If the variable is declared and set in the `Activity`, it works, but if the very same thing is attempted with the variable is declared in the `Fragment` and attempted to be set via a callback, then it fails, as referencing the `ImageView` in the `AppBarLayout` returns null. This can also be replicated by trying to set an icon in the `ActionBar` [`getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setIcon(Icon_Resource);`].

So the only way I found for this to work for an `activity` with a `fragment` meant to show details after being launched by an event like an `OnClick` event, is to *split* the `bundle` in the `intent`, by using part of it at the `Activity` level, then the rest at the `Fragment` level. That way the `AppBar` views can be set at the `Activity's` `OnCreate` while the views can be successfully referenced and the rest can be set within the inflated `Fragment` view.